# Turn screen off on sleep mode

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend

My problem is to put just my monitors to sleep. They are put to sleep after 5 minutes as specified in system settings, but after only a second  they wake up again - but showing only a black screen with the cursor.
Suspending the entire computer works just fine, as well does wake up afterwards.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.
My graphics card is a Nvidia quadro and I'm using the proprietary Nvidia driver version 361.42.